# How to increase RPS to 50k In gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

The highest RPS I could get to is 15k RPS. Adding more user threads just wouldn't increase RPS. Netstat, CPU, memory all look healthy in the Gatling host.

Is there any Gatling config parameters I can tune to attain 50k RPS?

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities:

1. You're saturating the bandwidth
2. Your system under load can't deal with more than this

Comment: i was hitting the health check endpoint of another service, and the data transfer rate is ~1.5m per second with 15k requests. 
I also suspect the service under test is the bottleneck. I wonder if Gatling by itself can reach 50k rps if bandwidth and service are not an issue.

Comment: We have some internal benchmarks that hit 200k rps so if you're not maxing out CPU or bandwidth, it's likely that your system under test can't reply fast enough.

Comment: I tried testing a bigger system, but the RPS can't get faster than 15k RPS. It'd be great if you know any Gatling config parameters I should look into.

Comment: bigger system = every component is bigger, eg including load balancers?

Comment: yeah, we were able to generate 20k+ RPS using another http request making tool like httpd

Comment: Are you sure you're using connections the same way? Like one tool opening new connections on each request and the other one reusing keep-alive ones with a global share connection pool?

Comment: For Gatling, we have set keepalive to true.

Comment: Please check this: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/b39346dc798ecdf7e8241dd8211de85157ff8164

Comment: what's difference between .shareConnections and .disableClientSharing?

Comment: in our test, turning shareConnections on/off doesn't change the RPS.

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell what's wrong your your env/test/app without any information. If you can provide a standalone reproducer, feel free to reach out on the Gatling community mailing list. Otherwise, if you need someone to investigate in your environment, that's only something we can provide as consulting.

Comment: disableClientSharing was something in older version, it no longer exists.

Comment: I'll do some profiling with my colleagues. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: instead looking into my application, may i ask what scenarios do you have in your benchmarking tests that reach 200k rps?

Comment: 1000 users looping and hitting a REST API that returns a small payload (so that we don't exceed the 1G bandwidth on our bare metal machines). As I said, as Gatling's architecture is no blocking, if you're not maxing out CPU or bandwidth on your injectors, it means  the bottleneck is your app.